# How do I apply a complex function using multiple DataFrame columns?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to perform a calculation on a DataFrame that would add a new column containing values that are sums of rows in another column of the same DataFrame. I've found other examples of feeding `apply()` multiple DataFrame columns, but I haven't seen an example that performs a query to find a *unique* set of values in another column.  The following code will set up a greatly simplified example:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ('Place_1','Place_2','Distance','Population_of_Place_2','SUM')
data = [('Alpha','Beta',5,324,0),
        ('Alpha','Gamma',9,42,324),
        ('Alpha','Delta',10,77,366),
        ('Beta','Alpha',5,101,0),
        ('Beta','Gamma',6,42,101),
        ('Beta','Delta',11,77,143),
        ('Gamma','Alpha',9,101,401),
        ('Gamma','Beta',6,324,0),
        ('Gamma','Delta',7,77,324),
        ('Delta','Alpha',10,101,42),
        ('Delta','Beta',11,324,143),
        ('Delta','Gamma',7,42,0)]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=data, columns=columns)


   Place_1 Place_2  Distance  Population_of_Place_2  SUM
0    Alpha    Beta         5                    324    0
1    Alpha   Gamma         9                     42  324
2    Alpha   Delta        10                     77  366
3     Beta   Alpha         5                    101    0
4     Beta   Gamma         6                     42  101
5     Beta   Delta        11                     77  143
6    Gamma   Alpha         9                    101  401
7    Gamma    Beta         6                    324    0
8    Gamma   Delta         7                     77  324
9    Delta   Alpha        10                    101   42
10   Delta    Beta        11                    324  143
11   Delta   Gamma         7                     42    0
```

The new column I'm trying to generate is **SUM**. Thinking of this as a row-wise calculation, I need to find all rows with a **Distance** value smaller than the current row, then calculate the sum of the population of those rows (i.e., **Population_of_Place_2**).

For example, the first three rows tell us that there are no locations closer to **Alpha** than **Beta**. So the value of **SUM** for the first row is 0.

However, when we evaluate the second row, we should find that location **Beta** is closer than **Gamma**: the distance value is 5 versus 9, respectively. So the value of **SUM** for row two is just the population of **Beta**, since **Delta** is still further way (**Distance** == 10).

Finally, when we evaluate the third row, there are now two locations (**Alpha** and **Gamma**) closer in proximity, so we population **SUM** with the sum of their populations.

My hunch is that I can accomplish this with some clever use of `apply()` and/or `groupby()` - which I've tried - but so far I haven't had any luck. I guess my biggest hope is that someone will tell me if this can't be accomplished cleanly and efficiently in pandas, so I can just move on to something clunkier.

Comment: I'm getting confused as to what you are trying to accomplish? I know you've done a lot of explaining, but can you give an expected output?

Comment: @MattR The **SUM** column is the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `sort_values` on your dataframe by Distance, use `groupby`, then `shift` to ignore the first value of that group and `cumsum`, lastly `fillna` with zero.  If you need convert back to integer use `astype`.

```
df['SUM'] = (df.sort_values(['Distance'])
               .groupby('Place_1')['Population_of_Place_2']
               .transform(lambda x: x.shift(1).cumsum())
               .fillna(0)).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   Place_1 Place_2  Distance  Population_of_Place_2  SUM
0    Alpha    Beta         5                    324    0
1    Alpha   Gamma         9                     42  324
2    Alpha   Delta        10                     77  366
3     Beta   Alpha         5                    101    0
4     Beta   Gamma         6                     42  101
5     Beta   Delta        11                     77  143
6    Gamma   Alpha         9                    101  401
7    Gamma    Beta         6                    324    0
8    Gamma   Delta         7                     77  324
9    Delta   Alpha        10                    101   42
10   Delta    Beta        11                    324  143
11   Delta   Gamma         7                     42    0
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Only one line, and completes in ~5 seconds for ~one million rows. Thanks man.

Comment: @Phil, thank you!  I am glad that worked.  Happy coding!